# Comparison in python (!= vs ==)

Tags: python, comparison-operators, language-implementation

I guess it's a common case to search an odd number with expression **num%2 != 0**.
Wonder what stands behind it comparing to **num%2 == 1**, especially in terms of its implementation in python.

Comment: There's no difference except one results in a jump if true, the other is a jump if false

Comment: I don't think I've ever actually seen anyone write it either way since zero is falsy in a boolean context: `if num % 2:` or as frequently `is_odd = lambda n: not n or n % 2`

Comment: The `not n` isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that while the workings are probably the same (haven't done any tests, but I don't expect any speed differences), the former is imho slightly more descriptive. That one says, execute if `num` is not divisible by 2. The latter one says, execute if `num` divided by 2 gives a remainder of one. While it may be completely equivalent for integers in this case, when using divisors greater than 2, having a remainder of 1 does not cover all cases where `num` is not divisible by `x`. Note that there is a case where you definitely should use the latter: when interested only in odd numbers and your inputs may be floats. I would consider 1.1 to be not odd (though not even either), but it has a remainder unequal to 0 when divided by 2.